# Как преобразовать список?

Tags: python, list

Есть файл с данными в таком виде:

```
1 2
4 1
5 4
1 1
5 3
6 1
```

Нужно из него сделать такой список:

```
[
    [
        [1, 2], 
        [4, 1], 
        [5, 4]
    ],
    [
        [1, 1], 
        [5, 3], 
        [6, 1]
    ]
]
```

То есть разбить по парам и каждые 3 пары в список.
Пока только смог сделать так:

```
['1', '2', '4', '1', '5', '4', '1', '1', '5', '3', '6', '1']
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def parseFile(file):
    arr = [list(line.split()) for line in file]
    return [[arr[i],arr[i+1],arr[i+2]] for i in range(0, len(arr)-2, 3)]

with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    arr = parseFile(file)
```

По идее должно работать, не проверял, извините)
Но идею вы поняли:

1. читаем файл построчно
2. каждую строку разбиваем по пробелу и приводим к типу список
3. всё это оборачиваем в список
4. проходим по каждому третьему элементу этого списка, начиная с первого
5. суём по три элемента в список для каждой итерации
6. оборачиваем это всё в список

Если я где-то допустил ошибку, то где-то промахнулся с индексами.

Если так, то поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Буду чекать, спасибо!

Comment: не забудьте галочку слева

Comment: почему то только первые 3 строки обрабатывает, а дальше нет.

Comment: поправил, попробуйте теперь (из len(arr) вычел на единицу меньше)

Comment: Все супер! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```
with open(file, 'r') as file:
    splitedList = [line.split() for line in file]
    resultList = [splitedList[a:a+3] for a in range(0, len(splitedList), 3)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Из вашего варианта результат можно получить вот так:

```py
list = ['1', '2', '4', '1', '5', '4', '1', '1', '5', '3', '6', '1']
threelists = []
out = []
j=0
for i, k in zip(list[0::2], list[1::2]):
    threelists.append([int(i), int(k)])
    j+=1

    if j%3==0 and j!=0:
        out.append(threelists)
        threelists = []

print(out)
```

Полное решение предлагаю такое:

Для открытия файла можно использовать `open()`

А `open().readlines()` вернет список сток

Пройдемся циклом по полученному списку, используем `enumerate` для получения номера итерации

Каждую 3 итерацию создадим новый список:

```py
filename = "path/to/file"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

out = []
list2 = []

for i, j in enumerate(data):
    line = [int(item) for item in j.split()]
    list2.append(line)

    if (i+1)%3==0 and i!=0:
        out.append(list2)
        list2 = []

print(out)
```

Comment: Спасибо, решение крутое, но туда попадают пустые элементы массива.